# Assigning Testplan from Code when using Locust as a Library and Outputting to Timescale

Tags: locust, timescaledb

When using locust as a library and redirecting the outputs to timescaledb all requests are logged with same run_id and testplan, I want somehow a method to distinguish between test to group different tests to different dashboards.

I tried changing request headers but not able to modify testplan variable in any way. I want somehow to dynamically assing test plans from code when using locust as a library to assign different dashboards to different testruns.

[Table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6L7d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the test plan name by passing `--override-plan-name <yourname>` or using env var `LOCUST_OVERRIDE_PLAN_NAME`.

A new `run_id` should be generated whenever a new test is started, are you sure this is not the case? Not that it would help differentiate the runs very much in Grafana...

Comment: Greetings, thanks again for the answer the run id generated is datetime based actually what I want is to aggregate different testruns with different platforms, I have to somewhat use a dictionary of times that would relate to platforms and it would grow in size, I will try to env variable approach.